# css file not finding image for background

Tags: html, css, django

I am experimenting with creating my first webpage. I am trying to get an image as my background but while testing with localhost it is not appearing, though all other css formatting is. I've gone through the other stackoverflow question relating to similar issues (seems common) but nothing has worked.

I have also tried the .jpg file in the same folder as the .css file (this is the current arrangement.

Below is the code as I currently have it...

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<title>lvl6</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'pages/style.css' %}">

<header class="header">
  <div class="header-text">Sign in via:</div>
  <a href="#" class="header-link">LinkedIn</a>
  <a href="#" class="header-link">Facebook</a>
</header>


<section class="landing-section landing-main">

  <h1 class="brand">lvl6</h1>
  <p class="landing-main-text">
    "Creating a future environment within which the human soul is destined to Flourish"
    <br>
    <br>
    subtext....
  </p>
</section>
```

style.css

```
.landing-section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.landing-main {
  background: url("stock.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;

  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.header-link {
  margin: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #c55e00;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc;
}

.header-text {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

'stock.jpg' is in the same folder as 'style.css'. I tried to create a directory for images and place it there but was not able to get the page to pick it up from there either.

I looked in the developer tool through chrome and here is what was shown in the path and folders...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqFh5.png)

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: from the picture you placed, it seems that the picture is not in the same folder with .css file !!

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? If yes then please share link. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui I have only deployed it on the local server (using python/django).

Comment: @Adnanj  It won't let me paste the snip of the file path from Atom but here is the file path for the css file

project-folder/pages/static/pages/style.css

file path for the pic... 

project-folder/pages/static/pages/stock.jpg

the file page for the html file (if this matters)...

project-folder/pages/templates/pages/index.html

Comment: In screenshot you share there 3 console error have you checked these errors? Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui,,, I tried to replicate what I had done before but only have 1 error now (I might have screwed something up previously with all of my attempts to get things to work that resulted in more errors). The one that exists currently is... 

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui... Also, if I try simple code, all in html, just to see if I can get a pic to work, I can get it to work when I put the file path directly into the browser, but not when I use the localhost. Then I get the error "GET http://localhost:8000/images/badge1.gif 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Sorry to say but i can't help you out until you share the complete code. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui   That's a lot of code, given the ! Is there a best way to do that like pushing it to github and sharing that link? Forgive my ignorance. I'm still just a newbie. Let me know what works best and I am happy to do so.

Comment: Pushed your code to github and share the link would be fine. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui... Here is the link... https://github.com/jmd10/lvl6lp.git

Trying to get one of the images as a background image. I have managed to get a gif from web url to do this, but not a local image or jpg. Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Comment: @jmd_10 your code seems fine, just one suggestion for the future try to put all your images assets in one directory. I just upload your basic code structure on https://repl.it/repls/SaneGlassPassword. Thanks

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui... Thanks for the help. Sorry I can't upvote you. You deserve it :)

Comment: I'm not helping others for points or votes. Your positive comment it's more than an upvote. Thank You :)